# store php response in angularjs service, then get them in controller

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, deferred

So, I am new to angularjs. I want to use MVC structure. So, I was thinking that storing the response from php in my service, then use them in my controller.

Service:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('dataService').service("incidentService", function ($http) {
    var Data = [];

    return ({
        getData: __getData
    });


    function __getData() {
        return Data;
    }

    function __setData($http, $q) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get('PHP/NAME.php',{cache : 'true'}).
        success(function(data){
            Data = data;
            console.log(Data);
            defer.resolve(data);
            defer.promise.then(function(data){
                Data = data;
                console.log(Data);
            });
        });
    }
})})();
```

Controller:

```
(function () {

 angular.module('app')
  .controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);

 /** @ngInject */
 function Ctrl($scope, $http, $q,baConfig, incidentService) {

  incidentService.setData($http,$q)

  var DataSet = incidentService.getData();
  console.log(DataSet);
 }
})();
```

By doing this way, the problem is my dataSet does not get updated when the data array in my service is updated. I know that we can return a defer promise to controller to get the data, but can we set the data first in service, then use get method to use them?

Comment: Can you post the entire definitions for the service and the controller. There are some fundamental flaws in the code above and it'd be better to see all of it.

Comment: Also, not sure what version of Angular you're using, but success has been deprecated. Use then like I have below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think the biggest issue with why this doesn't work is because you're assigned the data returned by the $http call to nData rather than just Data.

The next issue is that there's not a getMonthlyData method defined on the service.

That being said, this looks overly complicated.

Your service should look more like this:

```
(function () {
  angular.module('dataService').service("incidentService", function ($http,$q) {
    var service    
    service.getData = __getData()
    return service

    function __getData() {
        if (!service.Data) {
        return $http.get('PHP/NAME.php',{cache : 'true'}).then( function(data) {
            service.Data = data
            return $q.when(service.Data)
        })} 
        else {
             return $q.when(service.Data)
        } 
    }
})})();
```

Then in your controller you just get the data via `incidentService.getData()`

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The getMonthlyData() is a typo. It should be getData(). I still have one question. How should I store data I get in the service.

Comment: I'm storing it in the data property. return $q.when(service.Data) makes use of the cached data on subsequent calls. In both cases it's wrapped in a promise so in your controllers you can use incidentService.getData().then(...) to reference it, or in instances where you know the service has to have been called, you can simply reference incidentService.data.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to store several arrays in my service?

Comment: You'd basically do it the same way, just use a different property name for each one in place of where I used Data above.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. My reputation is too low to up votes. So I can only take this as accepted answer.

Comment: NP. Glad to help. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I have property undefined error now. Should I define these data property somewhere in advance?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Are you trying to reference incidentService.Data before you call incidentService.getData()?  This has really spun into a thread, it might be more clear if you open another question.

Comment: NVM. I fixed. I think I kind of get your idea. By returning a promise, we can save the number of http calls. You service variable is to check whether we make a http call or not.